# What is the relationship between the relations defining a subspace of a vector space and its dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was reviewing some linear algebra and in looking at some questions which involve finding a basis for a subspace defined in terms of relations between vector components, I thought about the above question.

To get a better idea of what I mean, consider the following standard Linear Algebra problem:

Let $U$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^5$ defined by $U=\{(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5)\in \mathbb{C}^5 : 6z_1=z_2, z_3+2z_4+3z_5=0\}$. Find a basis for $U$.

In this instance the subspace is defined by the relations $6z_1=z_2$ and $z_3+2z_4+3z_5=0$.

In this instance we can obviously conclude that the subspace is of dimension less than $5$, and finding the dimension of this subspace is not difficult, but for other arbitrary subspaces of vector spaces of very high (or possibly infinite) dimension, are there any results regarding the number of relations defining a subspace and its possible dimension?

For example, For a subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space defined by $l$ relations, the dimension is (some expression involving $l$, and $n$).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sean Penn would know

Comment: After what he did to me, I don't even want to hear that name.

Comment: whoops sorry let me correct that

Comment: I would think it would be $n-l$ because every *linear* relation can be written as $z_i = \sum_{j\neq i} a_j z_j$ after a little bit of algebra. This is assuming no redundancies, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start in a vector space of finite dimension$~n$, the rank-nullity theorem says that if your system of $l$ linear homogeneous relations has rank$~r$ (which means that you can choose $r$ independent relations among them, and any remaining relations are just linear combinations of those $r$ relations), then the dimension of the subspace defined by the relations is $n-r$.

In coordinates, every relation gives you the row of a matrix $A$, and your subspace is $\ker(A)$ (more precisely the kernel of the linear map given in coordinates by $A$). The rank of your matrix is maximal the number of linearly independent rows of your matrix, which one can find by row reduction. Thus finding the subspace is what Gaussian elimination is about; the number of free parameters to choose in a solution is the number $n$ of original unknowns, minus the number $r$ of (nonzero) equations after row reduction.

If you start with an infinite dimensional space, you'll need an infinite number of equations to bring down the dimension of the subspace to a finite number, and as you can imagine simply counting the relations (even if they are linearly independent) will not suffice to tell you the dimension of the solution space.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. Then linear relations on $V$ are vectors in the dual space $V^{*}$. If there are $l$ relations, the span $X$ of these relations can have dimension anywhere between $0$ and $\min(l,n)$. The subspace $X^{\bot}$ of $V$ defined by the relations is the subspace of $V$ orthogonal to $X$. The dimension of $X^{\bot}$ is $n - \dim X$, so it can range anywhere between $\max(n - l,0)$ and $n$.